# Save state of Checkbox in RecyclerView

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Using RecyclerView, I would like to save the Checkbox status.

I'm trying to use the shared preferences in this case and the code below is what I have but it doesn't work.

How can I use SharedPreferences in RecyclerView? Below is my Adapter class.

**Data adapter**

```
private Context mCtx;
private boolean isMyValueChecked;

private List<Final> resultList;

//getting the context and product list with constructor
public FavoriteAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Final> resultList) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.resultList = resultList;
}

@Override
public FavoriteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //inflating and returning our view holder
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_items, null);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= view.getContext().getSharedPreferences("My preference",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    isMyValueChecked= sharedPreferences.getBoolean("checkbox",false);

    return new FavoriteViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final FavoriteViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //getting the product of the specified position
    Final result = resultList.get(position);

    holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= v.getContext().getSharedPreferences("My preference",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("checkbox",holder.checkBox.isChecked());
            editor.apply();
        }
    });
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(isMyValueChecked);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return resultList.size();
}


class FavoriteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CheckBox checkBox;

    public FavoriteViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        checkBox=itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A RecyclerView creates only as many items as necessary. As soon as an item is no longer visible by scrolling, the content is modified via .onBindViewHolder() and appended below. The user doesn't notice this. However, you will probably need to make the following changes to your code:

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FavoriteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        return new FavoriteViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final FavoriteViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Final result = resultList.get(position);

        final String preferenceKey = "checkbox" + position;
        boolean isMyValueChecked= preferences.getBoolean(preferenceKey,false);
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(isMyValueChecked);

        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean newState) {
                preferences.edit().putBoolean(preferenceKey, newState).apply();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }


    class FavoriteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CheckBox checkBox;

        FavoriteViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            checkBox=itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        }
    }
}
```

I also changed the OnClickListener to an OnCheckedChangedListener. This is called as soon as the checkbox state has changed. An OnClickListener would be called every time the view was clicked.

I hope I've been able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

fetch value `isMyValueChecked` in `onBindViewHolder` instead of `onCreateViewHolder`.

and Use unique id to store value in shared preference because your value will be override if you use same key for every item.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final FavoriteViewHolder holder, int position) {
//getting the product of the specified position
Final result = resultList.get(position);

holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= v.getContext().getSharedPreferences("My preference",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(result.id,holder.checkBox.isChecked()); //use id instead of hard code checkbox
        editor.apply();
    }
});
isMyValueChecked= sharedPreferences.getBoolean(result.id,false); //fetch checked value
holder.checkBox.setChecked(isMyValueChecked);
}
```